# Force Inno Setup to show UAC prompt during installation

Tags: installation, inno-setup, privilege-elevation

How can I force Inno Setup to show UAC prompt if elevated privileges are required to run specific installator during my setup? Skipping to install this installator is not critical. I found out that I can specify AfterInstall function to test if privilege elevation is required (IsAdminLoggedOn()), but how to show UAC prompt to run this installator as specific user?

Comment: You'd have to re-run the setup and that requires to remember what user already selected during the wizard steps. Something very similar was asked in [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20197554/960757).

Comment: My case is quite different. There is no need to restart entire setup. I just want to run specific .exe during installation with elevated privileges. Your proposition about `runas` in question you pointed above helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. So, if you need to run specific installator with elevated privileges during your setup you need:

1. Specify your installator in `Files` section as follows:

   ```
   [Files]
   Source: "SomeSetup.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; AfterInstall: SomeSetupAfterInstall()
   ```
2. In `Code` section you shall define `SomeSetupAfterInstall()`. There you should run your  installator with `runas` verb using `ShellExec` if it is not admin launched setup. It might be like this:

   ```
   procedure SomeSetupAfterInstall();
   var
       ErrorCode: Integer;
       TmpPath: String;
       RunMethod: String;
   begin
       TmpPath:=ExpandConstant('{tmp}');
       if not IsAdminLoggedOn() then
       begin
           RunMethod := 'runas';
       end else
       begin
           RunMethod := '';
       end;
       ShellExec (RunMethod, TmpPath + '\SomeSetup.exe', '', '', 
                  SW_SHOW,  ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
   end;
   ```

Comment: I assume this means you're running your own setup with `PrivilegesRequired=lowest`.  Because otherwise the above would not be necessary.  (Don't forget that the user might cancel the elevation, or not be able to elevate, so your application will need to gracefully handle this component not being present.)

Comment: Yep. The point is to allow non-administrative users install an application, but without some specific features.